# Jquery - Each next element with class

Tags: jquery, function, class, each

I would like to target the "mesurefinal" class in a each function, from "mesureinitiale" class

```
<tr>
                        <td><label>1. Demi poitrine :</label></td>
                        <td><input class="mesureinitiale" id="vmesure0" disabled="disabled" type="text"></td>
                        <td>1,0</td>
                        <td>+2 / -2</td>
                        <td><input id="vpoitrinemodif" type="text"></td>
                        <td><input id="vpoitrinefinal" disabled="disabled" type="text" class="mesurefinale"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>2. Hauteur des épaules :</label></td>
                        <td><input disabled="disabled" class="mesureinitiale" type="text"></td>
                        <td>0,5</td>
                        <td>+1,5 / -1,5</td>
                        <td><input id="vpoitrinemodif" type="text"></td>
                        <td><input id="vpoitrinefinal" disabled="disabled" type="text" class="mesurefinale"></td>
                    </tr>
```

Comment: What is it that you exactly want?

Comment: I want to create a realtime calculation, based on "mesureinitiale" input, and the modification input.

Comment: I didn't ask that. What I meant was what do you mean by `target mesurefinal from mesureinitiale` class. You can target `mesureinitiale` directly also. And what event do you want to run while calling `mesurefinal`. If you could provide these details.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `each()` method provided by the `jQuery` libary to parse the `DOM` elements:

```js
$('.mesureinitiale').each(function(i, el){
  console.log(i, $(el).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td><label>1. Demi poitrine :</label></td>
  <td><input class="mesureinitiale" id="vmesure0" disabled="disabled" type="text" value='test 1'></td>
  <td>1,0</td>
  <td>+2 / -2</td>
  <td><input id="vpoitrinemodif" type="text"></td>
  <td><input id="vpoitrinefinal" disabled="disabled" type="text" class="mesurefinale" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><label>2. Hauteur des épaules :</label></td>
  <td><input disabled="disabled" class="mesureinitiale" type="text" value='test 2'></td>
  <td>0,5</td>
  <td>+1,5 / -1,5</td>
  <td><input id="vpoitrinemodif" type="text"></td>
  <td><input id="vpoitrinefinal" disabled="disabled" type="text" class="mesurefinale"></td>
</tr>
```

You can read more about `each()` method **[here](https://api.jquery.com/each/)**.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `each()` method to achieve this

using JQuery ,

```
 $('.mesureinitiale').each(function(){

 })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery for this, below code will work. I've taken `change` and `blur` events, change as per your requirements.

```
$('input.mesureinitiale').on("change blur", function(){
    $(this).closest("tr").find('input.mesurefinal');
});
```